# How do I check if a file is saved when the user tries to close the window button?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jframe

I have a couple of classes but I am only posting this Main class I have. Most of this code was taken from my professor's sample program. My problem is I want to run a check ONCE the window button is closed. The 'check' is going to see if a Boolean variable 'saved' from another class is True or False, and act accordingly. THEN, close the window. So far I have this, but I am getting an error from the JFrameL. How do I use the WindowClosing method from another class? I see that I am not supposed to call it on its own?

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main {

public static JFrameL frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a window.
    frame  = new JFrameL("Checking Account Actions");

    // Set the size of the window.
    frame.setSize(450, 350);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    CheckingAccountActions panel = new CheckingAccountActions();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();

    // Display the window
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class JFrameL extends JFrame {

    public JFrameL(String title) {
        super(title);
        FrameListener listener = new FrameListener();
        addWindowListener(listener);
    }

    private class FrameListener extends WindowAdapter {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("WindowListener method called: windowClosed.");
            if(!CheckingAccountActions.saved) {
                String  message = "The data in the application is not saved.\n"
                                + "Would you like to save it before exiting the application?";
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, message);

                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    CheckingAccountActions.chooseFile(2);
            }
            Main.frame.setVisible(false);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

 }
```

Error message I am receiving on line 2 from main():

"No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Main)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You appear to be trying to call instance methods in a static way. Don't do this.
2. I wouldn't extend JFrame for what you are trying to do.
3. I'd create my own WindowListener class, one that has a valid reference to the object that knows whether or not a file save is needed and whether it has been done.

e.g.,

```
class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {
  private CheckingAccountActions checkActions;

  public MyWindowAdapter(CheckingAccountActions checkActions) {
    this.checkActions = checkActions;
  }

  // in your window closing method
  // check the state of checkActions first before doing anything
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // note -- don't check for saved in a static way
        // use a method on the instance.
        if(!checkActions.getSaved()) {
            // etc...
        }

        JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
        frame.setVisible(false);

        // Main.frame.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Then in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame  = new JFrame("Checking Account Actions");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    CheckingAccountActions panel = new CheckingAccountActions();

    MyWindowAdapter winAdapter = new MyWindowAdapter(panel);
    frame.addWindowListener(winAdapter);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

**Edit**

This smells of static over-use: `CheckingAccountActions.saved`.

Comment: Okay. So which part of my program would this replace? And where am I calling this method? Because CheckingAccountActions is a class where all the activity goes on.

Comment: @EdoIsa: see edits. You appear to be using static methods and fields in a way you shouldn't, especially if save is a static variable -- don't do that. Also, get your JFrame from your WindowEvent parameter, e.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Just out of curiosity, WHY shouldn't I do that? This is for class btw, I am not making a program if security is the issue.

Comment: @EdoIsa: by misusing static, you lose all OOP advantages.

Comment: Don't static methods just make it accessible throughout the project? Sorry still a noob here. As far as I can understand, I would point to it being a security risk of other classes somehow misusing the static methods. Can you explain briefly or link where I can read more about misuse of Static methods? Hadn't heard of that before.

Comment: @EdoIsa: no, this has nothing to do with security. static methods and variables are methods and variables of the **class** not of the **instance** and so instances will not have their own version of these entities. They are useful in certain select situations such as constants, class counters, and utility methods, but otherwise should be avoided. They almost *never* should be used to try to make *global* variables. Just read up on good object-oriented practices, since this is all I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you need to do is move `panel` so you can access it later.

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main {

public static JFrameL frame;
public static CheckingAccountActions panel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a window.
    frame  = new JFrameL("Checking Account Actions");

    // Set the size of the window.
    frame.setSize(450, 350);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new CheckingAccountActions();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();

    // Display the window
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class JFrameL extends JFrame {

    public JFrameL(String title) {
        super(title);
        FrameListener listener = new FrameListener();
        addWindowListener(listener);
    }

    private class FrameListener extends WindowAdapter {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("WindowListener method called: windowClosed.");
            if(!panel.saved) {
                String  message = "The data in the application is not saved.\n"
                                + "Would you like to save it before exiting the application?";
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, message);

                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    panel.chooseFile(2);
            }
            Main.frame.setVisible(false);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```